# I passed a change event to the child component, but the state of the parent does not change

Tags: reactjs

At ReactJs I passed a change event to the child component, but I can't change the parent's state to show this value that came from the child.
I give a setState there at the parent, with the correct digit that comes from it, however the state does not change. Any help?

This father component:

```
import React from 'react';
import SnippetInput from './SnippetInput';
import BlockedInput from './BlockedInput';

export default class QuantityBlockedValue extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            valorinput: 1,
            valorbloqueado: 1
        }
        this.handleChangeSnippet = this.handleChangeSnippet.bind(this); //Event to passing to children
       
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let precoitem = (this.props.precoitem) ? this.props.precoitem : 1;
        this.setState({valorbloqueado: this.state.valorinput * precoitem});
    }

    //Passing event change to children and execute here
    handleChangeSnippet(event){
        let digito = event.target.value;        
        let digitoInt = parseInt(digito);
        if(digitoInt > 0){
            //digitoInt return correc number from children, but valorinput state dont update! why??
            this.setState({valorinput: digitoInt});            
        }  
    }    


    render(){        
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="center">
                        <h4>Quantity</h4>
                         <SnippetInput valorinput={this.state.valorinput} handleChange={this.handleChangeSnippet} />
                        
                         <h4>Value</h4>
                         <BlockedInput valorbloqueado={this.state.valorbloqueado}/>
                       
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The children component:

```
import React from "react";

export default class SnippetInput extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

       this.state = {
           valorinput : (this.props.valorinput) ? this.props.valorinput : 1
       }
      // this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       this.handleAumentar = this.handleAumentar.bind(this);
       this.handleDiminuir = this.handleDiminuir.bind(this);      
    }   

    handleAumentar(){
        let digitoAumentado = this.state.valorinput + 1;
        this.setState({valorinput: digitoAumentado});        
    }

    handleDiminuir(){
        let digito = this.state.valorinput;
        if(digito > 1){
            let digitoDiminuido = this.state.valorinput - 1;
            this.setState({valorinput: digitoDiminuido});
        }        
    }

    render(){

        let stylecorbotaodiminuir = "#F44336";
        let stylecorbotaoaumentar = "#009688";

        if(this.props.corBotaoDiminuir){
            stylecorbotaodiminuir = this.props.corBotaoDiminuir;
        }

        if(this.props.corBotaoAumentar){
            stylecorbotaoaumentar = this.props.corBotaoAumentar;
        }
        
        const stylebotaodiminuir = {
            display: "inline-block", 
            width: "50px",
            height: "50px",
            backgroundColor: stylecorbotaodiminuir,
            textAlign: "center"
        };

        const stylebotaoaumentar = {
            display: "inline-block",
            width: "50px",
            height: "50px",
            backgroundColor: stylecorbotaoaumentar,
            textAlign: "center"
        };
        
       return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div id="diminuir" className="noTextSelect" style={stylebotaodiminuir} onClick={this.handleDiminuir}>
                        <span style={{fontSize: "30px", padding: "10px"}}>-</span>
                    </div>
                    <input style={{"width":"150px","textAlign": "center"}} type="text" value={this.state.valorinput} onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>                    
                    <div id="aumentar" className="noTextSelect" style={stylebotaoaumentar} onClick={this.handleAumentar}>
                        <span style={{fontSize: "30px", padding: "10px"}}>+</span>  
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you are only reading `this.props.valorinput` in the constructor. The constructor won't be executed again as long as the elements exists.  See https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: You are right, looking at the link you gave me I realized that although the valorinput is updated in the parent with the correct value of the handleChange event, the child component does not update the state because I am only passing the value once to the constructor , as you also said.

Comment: The solution is to put this internal React function in the child component to update its state with the new props sent by the parent's onChange event:

componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
        // If there is an update in the props do:
        if (nextProps.valorinput! == this.props.valorinput) {
          // Update the status of valorinput
          this.setState ({
            valorinputchildren: nextProps.valorinput
          });
        }
    }

Comment: Thank you for helping me!
These are details that end up making programming difficult hehehe

Greetings from Brazil!